# Alfresco +NGINGX redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: http, nginx, https, reverse-proxy, alfresco

I am new to NGINX, and I already set up SSL for Alfresco with NGINX. Now I can use Alfresco with https://example.name/share. However, when I use http://example.name:8080/share, a login page occurs as well, but I cannot login use that http login page(https can).

My questions is how can I redirect all http page to https page? I have tried many methods online, but none of them work.

/opt/testAlfresco/tomcat/conf/server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <!-- Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" /-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <!-- Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" /-->

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="32768" 
               proxyPort="443" scheme="https" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="32768" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" maxHttpHeaderSize="32768" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" keystoreFile="/opt/testAlfresco/alf_data/keystore/ssl.keystore" keystorePass="kT9X6oe68t" keystoreType="JCEKS"
 secure="true" connectionTimeout="240000" truststoreFile="/opt/testAlfresco/alf_data/keystore/ssl.truststore" truststorePass="kT9X6oe68t" truststoreType="JCEKS"
               clientAuth="want" sslProtocol="TLS" allowUnsafeLegacyRenegotiation="true" maxHttpHeaderSize="32768" maxSavePostSize="-1" />  


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

/opt/testAlfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties

```
###############################
## Common Alfresco Properties #
###############################

dir.root=/opt/testAlfresco/alf_data

alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=127.0.0.1
alfresco.port=8080
alfresco.protocol=http

share.context=share
share.host=127.0.0.1
share.protocol=http

### database connection properties ###
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.username=alfresco
db.password=*********
db.name=alfresco
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${db.name}
# Note: your database must also be able to accept at least this many connections.  Please see your database documentation for instructions on how to configure this.
db.pool.max=275
db.pool.validate.query=SELECT 1

# The server mode. Set value here
# UNKNOWN | TEST | BACKUP | PRODUCTION
system.serverMode=PRODUCTION

### FTP Server Configuration ###
ftp.port=21

### RMI registry port for JMX ###
alfresco.rmi.services.port=50500

### External executable locations ###
ooo.exe=/opt/testAlfresco/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin
ooo.enabled=true
ooo.port=8100
img.root=/opt/testAlfresco/common
img.dyn=${img.root}/lib
img.exe=${img.root}/bin/convert
alfresco-pdf-renderer.root=/opt/testAlfresco/common/alfresco-pdf-renderer
alfresco-pdf-renderer.exe=${alfresco-pdf-renderer.root}/alfresco-pdf-renderer

jodconverter.enabled=false
jodconverter.officeHome=/opt/testAlfresco/libreoffice
jodconverter.portNumbers=8100

### Initial admin password ###
alfresco_user_store.adminpassword=*****

### E-mail site invitation setting ###
notification.email.siteinvite=false

### License location ###
dir.license.external=/opt/testAlfresco

### Solr indexing ###
index.subsystem.name=solr4
dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore
solr.host=localhost
solr.port.ssl=8443

### Allow extended ResultSet processing
security.anyDenyDenies=false

### Smart Folders Config Properties ###
smart.folders.enabled=false

### Remote JMX (Default: disabled) ###
alfresco.jmx.connector.enabled=false



# For more information on configuration,
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/
```

etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
  user nginx;
    worker_processes auto;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;
    
    # Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
    include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
    
    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
    }
    
    http {
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    
        sendfile            on;
        tcp_nopush          on;
        tcp_nodelay         on;
        keepalive_timeout   65;
        types_hash_max_size 4096;
    
        include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type        application/octet-stream;
    
        # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
        # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
        # for more information.
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    
        server {
            listen       80;
        return 500;
            listen       [::]:80;  
            server_name  _;
            root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOWALL";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
    
            location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
                if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                    return 204;
                }
            }
    
    
            # Load configuration files for the default server block.
            include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    
            #location / {
            #        }
    
            error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /404.html {
            }
    
            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
            }
    
        }
    
    # Settings for a TLS enabled server.
    #
    #    server {
    #        listen       443 ssl http2;
    #        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    #        server_name  _;
    #        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #
    #        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
    #        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
    #        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    #        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    #        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #
    #        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    #        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    #
    #        error_page 404 /404.html;
    #            location = /40x.html {
    #        }
    #
    #        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #            location = /50x.html {
    #        }
    #    }
    
        server {
            listen 443;
            server_name example.name.com;
            ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/***;
            ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/****;
            ssl on;
            ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
            ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
            access_log            /var/log/nginx/ssl.access.log;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
        add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOWALL";
            location / {
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443;
                proxy_redirect default;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
    
                if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                    return 204;
                }
            }
            ## This is the last curly bracket before editing the file.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't descibe what you tried so far. You run the risk of not getting any answers here at all if it is not recognized that you have made reasonable efforts to understand and solve the problem yourself.
I think you are getting a few things mixed up:

- 8080 is the tomcat port and should not be accessable from outside. Eather block it from your filewall or configure the connectors in server.xml to listen only on internal addresses like localhost (`address="127.0.0.1"`)
- If you want to redirect all requests from http to https received by nginx you find tons of examples in the net. e.g. the following virtual default host will redirect all requests to https:

  ```
  server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
      server_name _;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
  ```
- your nginx.conf looks like doing copy & paste but without the understanding why - at least from the security point of view.